# Step response of a given input and output (Laplace or Fourier)

Tags: fourier-transform, control-systems, laplace-transform, step-response

I am trying to calculate the step response of the following given:
Should I use Laplace transform or Fourier transform?
[image]

Comment: Neither. The easiest way is to this directly in the time domain.

Comment: Please update you question to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the mathematical expressions rather than a photograph.